# I can access website with server name, but with ip address system prompting i need to give username and password.

Tags: asp.net, iis, web, security

I have setup a test enviorment on server and there are few websites running on IIS.

Website security settings are set to 'integrated windows authentication' and anonymous access is unchecked.

When i access the website with the server name then it works fine but if i use an ip address instead then system prompting username password window.

> Why system is prompting username password window?
>
> How can i access a site with ip address and server name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are using Internet explorer, when there is a period in the URL it thinks that its an external address and will not pass on the credentials. So an IP address such as *'10.1.1.1'* will be treated as an external address, and as for an address like *'myhost'* it thinks its an internal address and pass on credentials

Have a look at this KB:

- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/258063
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb250483(VS.85).aspx

Comment: I use addresses on following format: http://192.165.5.5/intranet OR  http://SHDEV777/intranet

Comment: System only ask for user name & password the first time i visit the site (via ip address) but not after that even the remember password option is unchecked. But it might ask me after a while or if i restart my pc.

Comment: well your 1st address has periods it in it so it treats it as a external website. Just add that to the intranet zone and will hopefully not ask you for credentials.